# SwiftCSV error finding .csv file

Tags: ios, swift, csv

[Project File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtTMY.png)

I am experimenting with SwiftCSV to get data from a file, and so far I am having no luck. It seems like a very simple error that I cannot seem to fix - I am guessing it cannot find the file somehow. I have a "trainers.csv" file in the project (shown in screenshot) but every time I run this the code goes straight to the catch print statement - so there is something wrong in my try line.

```
func testCSV(){
    print("I got here")
    do {
        let csv = try CSV(name: "trainers.csv")
        print("Success?")

        //print(csv.rows)
    } catch {
        print("it was in this moment Adrian knew, he messed up.")
    }


}
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `CSV` class is expecting a full filename. Perhaps you should log the actual exception as part of your cute little message in the `catch` statement.

Comment: why not you try using NSBundle?

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about that! I am fairly new to swift and the syntax still catches me sometimes. It finds the file now, but now I get a **"The file “trainers.csv” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."** I think that's progress! I know what this one means, I will try to find the correct encoding method before asking for more help! Cheers~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their readme doesn't explain it very well, but looking into the `CSV` class the constructor you are using takes in a URL as a parameter (in other words a full path).  Then is uses that passed in path in `String(contentsOfURL: url)`.  So you need to get the full path to the file you are trying to load.

```
let csv = try CSV(name: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("trainers", ofType: "csv"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! printing the error now gives me **"The file “trainers.csv” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."**, which is better than before, so thank you! I will try to find the correct text encoding before coming back for more help! Thank you very much~